# PostgreSQL: An error occured in SQL statement: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I've created a stored procedure that works when using the command line and a DB manager (DBeaver).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scores(int, int, int) RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tab_scores WHERE pk_id = $1) THEN
        UPDATE tab_scores SET
        score = score + $2,
        most_recent_level = $3
        WHERE pk_id = $1;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO tab_scores(int, int, int) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I attempt to call this procedure through Java I get the following error:

> An error occured in SQL statement: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"
>     Position: 38

I've looked around and can't find a solution to this. I am using the postgresql-9.2 JDBC

Comment: Why does the error message say `RETURNING` while in your code you used `RETURNS`? Be precise with the code that you show.

Comment: I've posted the exact code and exact error message I'm receiving. I don't understand it either.

Comment: This error should be related to some else - your example has not keyword `RETURNING`.

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL logs to find out what statement your Java code is running to get the error. This is not it. Also, is there any chance you're on an old PostgreSQL version, or not on PostgreSQL at all but something like Redshift or Greenplum?